# Is there a way to sort the code as below in IntelliJ?(JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

```
{Header: "No|No|No", Type: "${sNoTy}", Hidden: Number("${sNoHdn}"), Width: "${sNoWdt}", Align: "Center", ColMerge: 0, SaveName: "sNo", Sort: 0},
{Header: "delete", Type: "${sDelTy}", Hidden: 1, Width: "${sDelWdt}", Align: "Center", ColMerge: 0, SaveName: "sDelete", Sort: 0},
```

Before

```
{Header: "No|No|No", Type: "${sNoTy}",  Hidden: Number("${sNoHdn}"),    Width: "${sNoWdt}",  Align: "Center", ColMerge: 0,    SaveName: "sNo",     Sort: 0},
{Header: "delete",   Type: "${sDelTy}", Hidden: 1, Width: "${sDelWdt}", Align: "Center",     ColMerge: 0,                     SaveName: "sDelete", Sort: 0},
```

After

Is there any way to do custom sorting in this format in IntelliJ?

Comment: can't see any notion of sorting here; would you like the object properties to be aligned?

Comment: That source is an array that JavaScript uses for the library. The format I want is:

`{key:value,\t\t\tkey:value,\t\t\tkey:value,\t\t\tkey:value,\t\t\tkey:value},{key:value,\t\t\tkey:value,\t\t\tkey:value,\t\t\tkey:value,\t\t\tkey:value}`